# How to package a .jar file using a java program

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar, executable-jar, packaging

How does one package a jar file using java code? I want a .jar file to be created with custom code whenever (for example) a button is pressed, how would I do this? There doesn't seem to be any documentation about this so I figured I would go here, I've tried searching everywhere on the web.

Comment: Basically wondering if this is even possible

Comment: See [`java.util.jar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/jar/package-summary.html), [`jdk.jartool`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/jdk.jartool/module-summary.html) + [`ToolProvider`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/spi/ToolProvider.html), or even [`ProcessBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html).

Comment: And the [ZIP File System Provider](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/jdk.zipfs/module-summary.html) (a JAR file is essentially just a ZIP file, by the way).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.

### The sequence of actions:

1. Need to pass Java code into the **JavaCompiler API**
2. FileManager extracts the source code for `JavaCompiler`
3. `JavaCompiler` compiles it and returns the bytecode
4. Generate an executable JAR. Create a `JarOutputStream` with a manifest that declares the main class.

### Technical articles on the topic:

[Baeldung: Compiling and Executing Code From a String in Java](https://www.baeldung.com/java-string-compile-execute-code#tools-and-strategy)

[Baeldung: Creating JAR Files Programmatically](https://www.baeldung.com/jar-create-programatically)